# Invalid svg to png conversion via rsvg in mediawiki

Tags: svg, png, mediawiki, rsvg

While uploading this [file](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%3aDragon.svg)  to my wiki instance, application uses `librsvg` to convert it into png thumbnails. But the result is like this [Link](http://postimg.org/image/9nv7itd9r/)

This dragon seems to be generated in Inkscape, so i tried to use inkscape as a converter. It worked for this image (but not for some others), but it has X dependencies, so I cannot use it.

[Here](http://mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aImage_administration#SVG) I found, that wikimedia projects use rsvg for such conversions.

Can anyone help me with this strange behavior?

Mediawiki settings for svg support:

```
# Svg support
$wgFileExtensions[] = 'svg';
$wgAllowTitlesInSVG = true;
$wgSVGConverter = 'rsvg';
```

Environment:

```
CentOS release 5.6 (Final)
rsvg version 2.16.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is damn simple — librsvg library was too old. 2.22.3+ solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

rsvg has a number of issues, please file a bug and mark it as blocker of https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8901 . It might already be in the list of known bugs, check.

Comment: Spent some time viewing their nice crosslinked system) Found no result